# How can I obfuscate the package names for two different `.aar` without having duplicate class collision?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

Let's say I have 3 subprojects (modules):

```
:libraryA
:libraryB
:app
```

`:app` depends on both `:libraryA` and `:libraryB`. In my libraries, I have:

```
// libraryA
com.example.libraryA.Class1
// libraryB
com.example.libraryB.Class2
```

When I run R8 (like proguard) over these two libraries, they generate the following classes:

```
// libraryA - Class1
a.a.a.a
// libraryB - Class2
a.a.a.a

(note that 2 different classes end up having the same signature)
```

When I build a variant of `:app` that uses the obfuscated `.aar`s of `:libraryA` and `:libraryB`, I get the following build failure:

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type a.a.a.a is defined multiple times:
```

One solution is to use `-keeppackagenames` in my proguard rules for the libraries

```
-keeppackagenames com.example.**
```

But I want to actually obfuscate the package name. What are my options here?

Is it possible to obfuscate package names in a unique but deterministic basis? For example, I would like the following to occur:

- `com.example.libraryA` -> `a.a.a`
- `com.example.libraryB` -> `a.a.b`

This would avoid any potential conflicts. Is something like this achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you package libraries with R8 for distribution you have to use `-keeppackagenames`, as otherwise consumers of the library can get duplicate classes.

There are options `-flattenpackagehierarchy` and `-repackageclasses` to control where non-kept classes go. For the R8 library itself [we use both](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/075aa99a0899913d3b153bcd8c7dea63bb084618/src/main/keep.txt#24).

However, when you are building a final app consuming the libraries all of the app including the libraries will be obfuscated as a whole, so the libraries does not have to be obfuscated when used as dependencies.